# Who selects which overloaded function to be executed in Java?

Tags: java, overloading

I'm learning Java and I have a question.
We can overload a method in various ways and the program executes just one. So the program has to determine which function to use.

My question is, who selects the function? Is it java compiler, or JVM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another name to Method Overload is **"compile-time polymorphism"**. At compile-time, java knows which method to call by checking the method signatures. So this is called compile-time polymorphism or static or early binding.

[There are two types of polymorphisms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-compile-time-and-run-time-polymorphism-in-java/). Another kind of polymorphism named as **"run-time polymorphism"**. This is achieved by Method Overriding (parent/child relationship in classes). Object is bound with the functionality at run time. Java virtual machine determines the proper method to call at the runtime, not at the compile time.

Answer (score 4):

Method overloading is handled by the java compiler at compile time based on arguments. Here's an example for method overloading:

```java
class Main{  
  void func(){System.out.println("No Params");}  
  void func(int a){System.out.println("Has Params");}   
}
```

Here's a link where you can learn more about it in detail: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3268983/java-challengers-1-method-overloading-in-the-jvm.html

Comment: So the number of overloaded method wouldn't effect program's exec time?

Comment: @백종헌 Not at all.